# How to access variables inside a movie clip from the timeline?

Tags: actionscript-3

I am making a side scrolling game using a virtual camera(Vcam) and I wanted a scoreboard that was in the Vcam movieclip so it would not just move off the screen when the character moved.

I am looking for a way to control the scoreboard(inside the Vcam movieclip) from the main timeline or an alternate way to have the scoreboard not move off the screen when the character moves.

The textField that is modified to make the scoreboard is called:

```
score
```

and the code I have used to update the scoreboard(before it was in the Vcam movieclip):

```
score.text = String(points)
```

...

...

> score

is the textbox

> points

is the number of points the player has

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would have to access the textbox as a property of the Vcam MovieClip.

So, assuming this is all public, you would do that like so:

```
Vcam.score.text = points;
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer--Worked perfectl, i was pretty sure that was the first thing I tried though :P